# getBoundingClientRect().width returning incorrect width

Tags: javascript, height, width, getboundingclientrect

I generally use `.getBoundingClientRect().width` when developing html5 banners to get the width and height in the JS. This is used to do animations per size with (if 120x600, if 160x600 etc). I have noticed on a recent Chrome update if the browser is zoomed in or out it returns an incorrect value (out by 0.0001px) which means the if statement / animations fail.

I tried `.getBoundingClientRect().width` with a round to nearest 10 function but i felt it was too hacky.

Another solutions was grabbing the height and width from the css style sheet.

Is there a better solution for doing this without hard coding in the dimensions of each banner size?